# JUnit in Intellij Idea generates empty test class body

Tags: java, unit-testing, intellij-idea, junit

Everytime I create a JUnit 5 test class in IntelliJ IDEA (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>) on my class, it generates blank test fixture with an empty method body.

e.g.

```
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;

class RegTest {

    @Test
    void insert() {
    }

    @Test
    void delete() {
    }
}
```

If I write into these methods assertions by myself, it works fine.

Shouldn't it prepare (generate) for instance valuables `expResult`, `data`, or `assertEquals(expResult,data)`?

Sorry to bother you, but I read JUnit FAQ and IntelliJ IDEA help and still am without clue.

Thank you

Comment: this is IntelliJ helping you with providing you with template methods where you can create your own tests in try cmd+n in intellij when in the classfile (ctrl+n on windows I guess) and see what  options you get...

Comment: Tests can take many forms. You may wish to assert exceptions being thrown, values being equal, mocks being called. Of maybe the inverse of all these. Given the variety of options, I think it's reasonable not to define a skeleton beyond the method call

Answer (score 4):

Under `Editor -> File and Code Templates`, you can define a template for a Java class (general).

Assuming that all your test classes end with `Test`, then you could edit that general template with the following:

```
#if (${PACKAGE_NAME} && ${PACKAGE_NAME} != "")package ${PACKAGE_NAME};#end

#if ($NAME.endsWith("Test"))
import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;
import static org.mockito.Mockito.*;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;
import static org.junit.jupiter.api.Assertions.*;
#end
#parse("File Header.java")
public class ${NAME} {

     @Test
     public void testTemplate() throws Exception{
         // Arrange


        // Act


        // Assert
     }       
}
```

in order to get the basic unit testing imports and have a ready template for your first test.